# What are metaclass bases in Python?

Tags: python, django, class, metaclass

I'm trying to extend django-allauth to do something specific to my projects. I'm basically trying to write my own wrapper on top of django-allauth, and want the installation, configuration and other stuff to be quite similar to allauth.

For this, I started with extending `AppSettings` class from `allauth/accounts/app_settings.py`. I created my own `app_settings.py` did something like this:

```
from allauth.account import app_settings as AllAuthAppSettings
class MyAppSettings (AllAuthAppSettings):
     def __init__(self, prefix):
         # do something
```

Also, at the end of the app_settings.py, I simply put the following (copying it from django-allauth itself):

```
import sys
my_app_settings = MyAppSettings('MY_PREFIX_')
my_app_settings.__name__ = __name__
sys.modules[__name__] = my_app_settings
```

Now, when I start my project, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Honestly, I'm quite new to the Python-Django world and don't really understand what's happening in those last four lines.

What is *metaclass bases*? What are the four arguments that are being passed to it? How do I make this flow work?

Here's the stack trace:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x104146578>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/user/myproject/my_app/models.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .model_managers import *
  File "/Users/user/myproject/my_app/model_managers.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import app_settings
  File "/Users/user/myproject/my_app/app_settings.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you should be able to inherit from `AllAuthAppSettings`

The `django-allauth` package is doing some very ugly python magic

```
import sys  # noqa
app_settings = AppSettings('ACCOUNT_')
app_settings.__name__ = __name__
sys.modules[__name__] = app_settings
```

Basically, when you import the `app_settings` module, it creates an instance of the `AppSettings` class, renames it to the name of the `app_settings` module, and then *replaces the imported module with the instance of the class*!

You cannot inherit from class instances.  I'm guessing you want to inherit from then non-instantiated `AppSettings` class.  To do that, you need to inherit from the `class` of `app_settings`, not `app_settings` directly

```
from allauth.account import app_settings as AllAuthAppSettings


class MyAppSettings(AllAuthAppSettings.__class__):
    ...
```

I don't think you should need to copy those lines from the end of the `app_settings` module to hack your module into a class.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I got the part about why is this a hacky way. However, I still get the same error on doing the above changes. Is there any way I can get the uninstantiated AppSettings class in my custom app_settings.py?

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this class?  Do you have the full traceback

Comment: I think so. I've added the complete stack trace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The issue was precisely what you'd pointed to and was resolved using the above method.